Am I still correct for getting a different answer for minimum value even when my points are the same?
I just solved a problem involving linear programming where I have to graph these equations:
$$\{(s,b) | s ≤ 45, s \in W, b \in W \}$$
$$\{(s,b) | s ≤ 55, s \in W, b \in W \}$$
$$\{(s,b) | s + b ≤ 85, s \in W, b \in W \}$$
$P = 0.75s + 0.10b$
The textbook got the vertices of the feasible region the opposite of mine. For example, if I got $(55,45)$ as one of the vertices, then the textbook got $(45, 55)$.
It's been mentioned that it doesn't matter which variable you assign x- and y- to, but I'm getting incorrect minimum values.
For example, the answer for the minimum value is $(45,40)$ but what I got was $(40,45)$ which happens to be the maximum value for the textbook.
Is there anything I should know when assigning a variable to an axis?

What is "s E W"? You can find out how to write mathematics better on this site by following this link: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

I'm not sure what you mean by "it's been mentioned" or "which variable you assign x- and y- to." Why can't you just plot $s$ and $b$ on a plane? This is less likely to result in transcription errors. But since we have not seen any of what you did to get your results, we cannot know where your mistake is. Show your work, and use the link in the previous comment to show it clearly using standard notation.

Please also check what you wrote. If $s\leq 45$ then $s\leq 55$, so the inequality (not equation!) $s\leq 55$ is redundant here.
